# How to display inbox messages and sent messages order by date - private message module

Tags: privatemsg

In private message module inbox and sent messages should be display by time wise.

Right now,

**It is displaying where the unread messages list first and then the read messages list second.**

But based on my requirement

**All the messages should be displayed in date order weather it is read or unread**

How can I do this?

Comment: Drupal 6 or 7? Possible in both, but requires a different hook.

Comment: @@Berdir: In drupal 6.. But i don't find any hook to do the same..  Could you guide me on this issue? thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following issue: http://drupal.org/node/850932